# I want to pass an id parameter when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm confused how do I pass an Id parameter to onClick function in javascript

```
checkboxClick=(e)=>{
  if(e.target.checked===true){
    console.log("checkbox clicked")
  }
}

<input type="checkbox" key={id} onClick={this.checkboxClick}/>
```

this is working properly but i also want to pass an id parameter to the checkboxClick() method and print that Id if e.target.checked=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.target.id` => will return the id of the checkbox

Also, Add id attribute in your HTML element

```
<input type="checkbox" key={id} id={id} onClick={this.checkboxClick}/>
```

Comment: i havent passed the id to the function so how its going to show..

Comment: note here Id is a variable with a numeric variable.

Comment: Event object i.e `e` in your code, you can name anything, will have all the attribute, param values, etc . Would suggest you to look into Event object in React

Comment: Type of id doesnt matter. Let it be string or number

Comment: You can see the documentation for alternatives https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html